# How to create a vector of smart pointers

Tags: c++, class, vector, smart-pointers

I am actually a beginner with C++, and I'm trying to learn to use C++ in professional way. Now, I've wrote a program to get limited number of staff's specification, including name, age, salary, and even provide user with ability to promote one who want. I defined a class and someone suggested me to use vector. Now, I am thinking that is there any way to use smart pointers for this stuff? I mean a way to mange memory and increase speed of the program?

Thanks.

Comment: If it is a non-polymorphic,value-type class, then just use `std::vector<Foo>`.  If it is a polymorphic or entity-type class, then use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Foo>>`.

Comment: About increasing the speed of your program: 1) Do not try to optimise if you don't have performance issues. 2) First try to write the cleanest code possible, this helps a lot the compilers to do their optimisations. 3) If you still have performance issues, profile your code before trying random optimisations.

Comment: Thank you, but is there anyway to use dynamically allocated memory (i.e. push_back ) ?